# MS CRM Get Total License available Programmatically

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamics-crm

Using C sharp code I need to read and prepare a report(Licenses) like Total Available and Used,Just like the office 365 portal's Dashboard(Billing->Licenses).

I just used the **Get-MsolUser** command to retrieved the licensed user to calculated the Used Licenses. In a  similar manner I need to fetch the result of Total Available Licenses.

Is there any possible way to retrieve it?

Hoping someone might have tried the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the result by querying the command **Get-MsolAccountSku** to get the ActiveUnits and ConsumedUnits